# Java superclass instantiation calling subclass method, not sure why

Tags: java, overriding, subclass, superclass

So I have a problem that looks something similar to this:

```
package com.blah.A_package;

public class A
{
    public void f() {
        g();
    }

    protected void g() {
        System.out.println("superclass g()");
    }
}

package com.blah.B_package;

public class B extends com.blah.A_package.A
{
    protected void g() {
        System.out.println("subclass g()");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    A scratch = new A();
    scratch.f();
}
```

When run, it prints out "subclass g()" instead of the expected "superclass g()".

We're actually creating objects of both the superclass and the subclass (this is through reflection on a jar), sticking them in a map, and then pulling them out as we need them, but we have verified by printing out the object.getClass().getName() and seeing that we are in fact working with the superclass instantiation.

Anyway, when we run the application, for some reason it's using the subclass copy of the method rather than the superclasses, despite the object being an instantiation of the superclass (ie, it shouldn't even know about the subclasses methods). Is this a known thing that myself and my coworkers aren't aware of? We're completely stumped on why this would ever be happening.

Comment: You're making a class extend a package??? I haven't ever seen that before!

Comment: This is completely unrunnable java. Where are the function return types????

Comment: Your code is wrong in many ways, please correct them first :)

Comment: Once you've got a short but complete program that actually *works* and demonstrates the problem, I'll believe you. Until then, I'll assume it's a diagnostic error...

Comment: What you are describing doesn't make sense, and your code is very broken.  1) Make your code runnable and 2) make sure it exhibits the behavior you describe.

Comment: What you're describing cannot happen... You probably have a `B` instance. Retrace your steps and you'll find the _real_ problem...

Comment: Guys. You're missing the point here. This isn't *the actual code*. Can you ignore the mistakes for now and focus on the problem I've described?

Comment: Would you not have a subclass of `B` named `A` in _another_ package (not the original superclass of `B`)?

Comment: There are no subclasses of B anywhere, and B is the only subclass of A.

Comment: The updated code does NOT produce the results you describe.  Please come up with a reproducible simplified test case.  In doing so, you'll likely end up finding out what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the only thing that can be causing this is that the runtime object is an instance of B, but you declared it as A. As the method is invoked, your program will start to look in the runtime class of the object it is invoked on, then work its way up the inheritance tree.

On a side note, you are missing constructors, your class B extends a package and your methods don't have return types. That is completely invalid Java.

Comment: I'm aware of the problems in the example. It's not the actual code. Please ignore them and focus on what's actually gone wrong.

We've verified, as I said, by printing out the obj.getClass().getName() that it is not an instantiation of the subclass.

Comment: I have a cold, sorry I did not smell that just now.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can cause that confusion is having a subclass of `B` with the same name as its superclass (`A`) *but* on a different package with a similar name of the package of the `A` superclass.

Apart from that, it looks like an analysis error. Retrace your steps. Some ideas: delete class `B` or make it uninstantiatable, then reintroduce it and test it all again.

Comment: There are no subclasses of B and B is the only subclass of A. We've printed out the full class name with obj.getClass().getName() and it is the superclass in question that's being used, not the subclass or some class in a different package.

Comment: But it still looks like an error in your analysis. Retrace your steps. Some ideas: delete class `B` or make it uninstantiatable, then reintroduce it and test it all again.

Comment: We've actually renamed B to something completely different, but saw the same behavior. Following that, we changed the method signature in the superclass to be different and modified calls to it to include the added parameter (to force the superclass method to always be called) and that fixed it, but obviously isn't going to work as a solution and still leaves the question open. Unfortunately, making it uninstantiable isn't an option.